# jekyll GitHub Metadata error

Tags: git, ubuntu, metadata, jekyll

I am using [this](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) to create a blog.
when i am running in local I am facing this error.

`GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/orgs/mones-cse: 404 - Not Found`.

the very first time there is no error but if I change anything for example change text in any post i got this error 2nd time.

bellow there is the full thing.

```
m1s@m1s-Aspire-4755:/media/m1s/062E0DE72E0DD11B/git/mones-blog$ bundle exec jekyll server
Configuration file: /media/m1s/062E0DE72E0DD11B/git/mones-blog/_config.yml
            Source: /media/m1s/062E0DE72E0DD11B/git/mones-blog
       Destination: /media/m1s/062E0DE72E0DD11B/git/mones-blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 16.848 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/media/m1s/062E0DE72E0DD11B/git/mones-blog'
Configuration file: /media/m1s/062E0DE72E0DD11B/git/mones-blog/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
      Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-10-23 14:30:10    GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/orgs/mones-cse: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
...done in 22.723471133 seconds.
```

just to add some additional information

- I have already added `JEKYLL_GITHUB_TOKEN` and `SSL_CERT_FILE` in my environment variable
- my GitHub username `mones-cse`
- my git repository name `mones-blog`

and this is my _config.yml file

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your entire site, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely need to edit after that.
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# `jekyll serve`. If you change this file, please restart the server process.

# Site Settings
locale                   : "en"
title                    : "Site Title"
title_separator          : "-"
name                     : "Monesul haque"
description              : "a test blog site"
url                      : #http://localhost:4000 # the base hostname & protocol for your site e.g. "https://mmistakes.github.io"
baseurl                  : # the subpath of your site, e.g. "/blog"
repository               : mones-cse/mones-blog # GitHub username/repo-name e.g. "mmistakes/minimal-mistakes"
teaser                   : # filename of teaser fallback teaser image placed in /images/, .e.g. "500x300.png"
# breadcrumbs            : false # true, false (default)
words_per_minute         : 200
comments:
  provider               : # false (default), "disqus", "discourse", "facebook", "google-plus", "staticman", "custom"
  disqus:
    shortname            : # https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466208-what-s-a-shortname-
  discourse:
    server               : # https://meta.discourse.org/t/embedding-discourse-comments-via-javascript/31963 , e.g.: meta.discourse.org
  facebook:
    # https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
    appid                :
    num_posts            : # 5 (default)
    colorscheme          : # "light" (default), "dark"
staticman:
  allowedFields          : ['name', 'email', 'url', 'message']
  branch                 : # "master", "gh-pages"
  commitMessage          : "New comment."
  filename               : comment-{@timestamp}
  format                 : "yml"
  moderation             : true
  path                   : "_data/comments/{options.slug}"
  requiredFields         : ['name', 'email', 'message']
  transforms:
    email                : "md5"
  generatedFields:
    date:
      type               : "date"
      options:
        format           : "iso8601" # "iso8601" (default), "timestamp-seconds", "timestamp-milliseconds"
atom_feed:
  path                   : # blank (default) uses feed.xml

# SEO Related
google_site_verification :
bing_site_verification   :
alexa_site_verification  :
yandex_site_verification :

# Social Sharing
twitter:
  username               :
facebook:
  username               :
  app_id                 :
  publisher              :
og_image                 : # Open Graph/Twitter default site image
# For specifying social profiles
# - https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/social-profiles
social:
  type                   : # Person or Organization (defaults to Person)
  name                   : # If the user or organization name differs from the site's name
  links: # An array of links to social media profiles

# Analytics
analytics:
  provider               : false # false (default), "google", "google-universal", "custom"
  google:
    tracking_id          :


# Site Author
author:
  name             : "Monesul haque"
  avatar           : "bio-photo.jpg"
  bio              : "knowledge is the power."
  location         : "Dhaka,Bangladesh"
  email            : "mones-cse@gmail.com"
  uri              :
  bitbucket        : 
  codepen          : 
  dribbble         :
  flickr           :  
  facebook         : 
  foursquare       :
  github           :
  google_plus      :
  keybase          :
  instagram        :
  lastfm           :
  linkedin         :
  pinterest        :
  soundcloud       :
  stackoverflow    : # "123456/username" (the last part of your profile url, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/username)
  steam            :
  tumblr           :
  twitter          : 
  vine             :
  weibo            :
  xing             :
  youtube          :


# Reading Files
include:
  - .htaccess
  - _pages
exclude:
  - "*.sublime-project"
  - "*.sublime-workspace"
  - vendor
  - .asset-cache
  - .bundle
  - .jekyll-assets-cache
  - .sass-cache
  - assets/js/plugins
  - assets/js/_main.js
  - assets/js/vendor
  - Capfile
  - CHANGELOG
  - config
  - Gemfile
  - Gruntfile.js
  - gulpfile.js
  - LICENSE
  - log
  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - Rakefile
  - README
  - tmp
keep_files:
  - .git
  - .svn
encoding: "utf-8"
markdown_ext: "markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md"


# Conversion
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
lsi: false
excerpt_separator: "\n\n"
incremental: false


# Markdown Processing
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  hard_wrap: false
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  smart_quotes: lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  enable_coderay: false


# Sass/SCSS
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed # http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style


# Outputting
permalink: /:categories/:title/
paginate: 5 # amount of posts to show
paginate_path: /page:num/
timezone: # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones


# Plugins
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-feed
  - jemoji
  - jekyll-github-metadata # if not work delete

# mimic GitHub Pages with --safe
whitelist:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
  - jekyll-gist
  - jekyll-feed
  - jemoji


# Archives
#  Type
#  - GitHub Pages compatible archive pages built with Liquid ~> type: liquid (default)
#  - Jekyll Archives plugin archive pages ~> type: jekyll-archives
#  Path (examples)
#  - Archive page should exist at path when using Liquid method or you can
#    expect broken links (especially with breadcrumbs enabled)
#  - <base_path>/tags/my-awesome-tag/index.html ~> path: /tags/
#  - <base_path/categories/my-awesome-category/index.html ~> path: /categories/
#  - <base_path/my-awesome-category/index.html ~> path: /
category_archive:
  type: liquid
  path: /categories/
tag_archive:
  type: liquid
  path: /tags/
# https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives
# jekyll-archives:
#   enabled:
#     - categories
#     - tags
#   layouts:
#     category: archive-taxonomy
#     tag: archive-taxonomy
#   permalinks:
#     category: /categories/:name/
#     tag: /tags/:name/


# HTML Compression
# - http://jch.penibelst.de/
compress_html:
  clippings: all
  ignore:
    envs: development
```

i tried `bundle exec jekyll server --verbose`
output is

```
 GitHub Metadata: Initializing...
   GitHub Metadata: Calling @client.contributors("mones-cse/mones-blog")
   GitHub Metadata: Calling @client.repository("mones-cse/mones-blog")
   GitHub Metadata: Calling @client.organization("mones-cse")
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/orgs/mones-cse: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
   GitHub Metadata: Calling @client.list_repos("mones-cse", {"type"=>"public"})
   GitHub Metadata: Calling @client.releases("mones-cse/mones-blog")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the exactly same error.
I think it is a bug of github-metadata.
I found that error does not affect my server running.
When I update something, the result will be displayed in my browser.

I have used curl to test Github's API, the tutorial is here:
https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/

If I substitute the "orgs" in the wrong url to "user", then everything is ok.
So I think it is github-metadata's fault that generates wrong url.